# ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Resources do not apply

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I am currently trying to style a MenuFlyout using ToggleMenuFlyoutItems [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.togglemenuflyoutitem?view=winrt-22621) are the resources of ToggleMenuFlyoutItems listed.
If I override those resources nothing changes.

These are my desired resources and colors.

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemBackground" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource VividSkyBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemBackgroundPressed" Color="{ThemeResource StarCommandBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemBackgroundDisabled" Color="{ThemeResource LightBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemForeground" Color="{ThemeResource PitchBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource PitchBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemForegroundPressed" Color="{ThemeResource PitchBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemCheckGlyphForeground" Color="{ThemeResource TabascoRedColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemCheckGlyphForegroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource VikingGreenColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemCheckGlyphForegroundPressed" Color="{ThemeResource PitchBlackColor}"/>
```

is this a known problem or does anyone no a reason/solution?

Greetings

Comment: Light weight styling are kind of broken in WinUI 3 I guess. You might need to restyle you ``ToggleMenuFlyoutItem`` until they fix it.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding that does not sound good haha. But thank you for your information guess I have to do it!

Comment: @tiko, be sure to [open an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) to get it fixed.

Comment: @EddieLotter will do!